# Vertical alignment of a nav within a div

Tags: html, css

I want to create a navigation bar, which is vertically aligned within its parent div. Here is my code:

```css
div#banner {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}

div#title {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav#menu {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav#menu ul {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

nav#menu ul li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav#menu ul li a {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">

  <div id="title">
    <h1>The Title</h1>
  </div>

  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

To try to make the "menu" vertically aligned within the "title", I gave the "menu" "display: inline-block", and "vertial-align: middle".

However, the menu is displayed at the top of the surrounding div, rather than in the middle.

What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way and modern one is using flex ,
for the div#banner add :
display:flex;
align-items:center;

```css
div#banner {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

div#title {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav#menu {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav#menu ul {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

nav#menu ul li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav#menu ul li a {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">

  <div id="title">
    <h1>The Title</h1>
  </div>

  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a couple of lines, changing this to a flexbox layout. This way you will have far more control over sizing and positioning of the navigation.

```css
div#banner {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex; <- this
  align-items: center; <- and this
}

div#title {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav#menu {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav#menu ul {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

nav#menu ul li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav#menu ul li a {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">

  <div id="title">
    <h1>The Title</h1>
  </div>

  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your **CSS** with this:

```
div#banner {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div#title {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav#menu {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav#menu ul {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

nav#menu ul li {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

nav#menu ul li a {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to nav#menu:

```
nav#menu {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```